# How to fix IP address issues after server migration

Tags: ip, virtual-hosts

For the sake of discussion and clarity:
Old ip = 12.345.6.789
New ip = 98.765.432.10

I created a development Wordpress server/site on a local virtualbox machine that had a bridged connection which assigned it a unique IP address. Once development was complete the whole VM was then imported into a production VMWare vServer. I made the appropriate changes in the MySQL database to change the IP address from the old IP to the new production IP and everything is working as expected with one exception. When any links or content are clicked or accessed in the production version, the browser shows "Waiting for 12.345.6.789..." while resolving to the correct ip of 98.765.432.10/about (etc.).

Where is this old IP stored that it is attempting to be accessed if not in the MySQL database? I have scoured the config files and databases and find no instance of the old IP anywhere, leading me to believe it is hard coded somewhere from the initial setup in the dev environment.

Comment: How did you go about finding & replacing the ip's in the database?

Comment: It's best to use a plugin for this sort of migration - especially since your IP addresses do not have the same string length. It's also possible you are cached. I would first try loading things in a different web browser or at least one where you have completely deleted the browsing history and restarted the browser. If you still have problems, go back and find a database migration plugin - best if you work from a backup before you manually replaced anything but should still work on what you currently have. That way if there are serialized CDN settings etc. it will be fixed properly.

Answer (score 1):

I used phpMyAdmin to make the changes. I have found the solution and wanted to share in case anyone else comes across this. The issue was in a background image that had been uploaded in the development environment. When the page was rendering it was trying to call that image from the old IP. I discovered the root cause by using Developer Tools in Chrome to view the page source. I corrected the issue by re-uploading the image from my production environment, thereby changing the source IP. Thank you for your response.

To further respond to your suggestions, I didn't do a database migration so no migration tools were needed. I imported the entire operating system from one virtual environment to another, specifically to avoid the complications involved with that. It was just a matter of adjusting the domain name/IP addresses within the MySQL database at that point.